# Flutter: cloud_firestore_web-3.1.1 Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'

Tags: flutter

Problema occoreu após atualizar o flutter e as dependências, e ao lançar o app em chorme(web)

> sdk: '>=3.0.0-35.0.dev <4.0.0'
>
> cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
> firebase_core: ^2.4.0
> cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
> firebase_auth: ^4.2.1

Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode... Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome... ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cloud_firestore_web-3.1.1/lib/src/utils/web_utils.dart:71:13: Error: Method not found: 'FallThroughError'. throw FallThroughError(); ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que este é um erro já reportado https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10140

A solução tempoprária é abrir o ficheiro do erro (load_bundle_tast_state.dart) com o (cmd+click), e na linha 17 mudar:

> throw FallThroughError();

para

> throw UnsupportedError('Unknown LoadBundleTaskState value: $state.');

UPDATE: cloud_firestore: ^4.3.0 já resolveu a situação!